# Post a status in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, razor

I have 'statusupdateform.cshtml'. Now, I want to post the status on click of 'Share'.

The database query is in 'statusupdateform.cshtml'.

I want to perform this in ajax.

Then after the post, the result should show in another file 'newsfeed.cshtml' under the div 'media-object'.

Both the files 'statusupdateform.cshtml' and 'newsfeed.cshtml' are rendered in 'home.cshtml'

P.S.
The files are working correctly without ajax, i.e. the queries from the database are alright.

However, I can't implement this in ajax.

Can anybody help please?

Comment: did you try anything ?

Comment: I really don't know much about ajax. However, I tried to implement the requested with the help of this link:http://www.9lessons.info/2009/11/insert-delete-with-jquery-and-ajax.html

Comment: Can you show us what you've done? with a code snippet? That link is for php as a warning, as I noticed you tagged razor... Also, try taking a look at this if you like, as it falls more in line with what you are doing. http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/Article/220/Posting-Data-With-jQuery-AJAX-In-ASP.NET-Razor-Web-Pages

Comment: Still couldn't do anything.... '<script>
   $(function () {
        $("button").click(function () {
            var car = { Make: 'Audi', Model: 'A4 Avant', Colour: 'Black', Registered: 2013 }; //don't know what to use here
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "statusupdateform.cshtml",
                data: car, //no idea what to pass here
                datatype: "html",
                success: function (data) {
                    $('#result').html(data); //this should be in the newsfeed
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>'

Comment: Why not make an ajax.Post()   form   and post the data to the controller and send  data to the database there, i see no valid reason doing it as u are describing it.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do something like the following and provide the filled out form as a model to the controller and do DB-insertions from there?

Stripped down example;

```
using (Ajax.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", new AjaxOptions()
{
    HttpMethod = "POST",
    OnBegin = "CanHaveJsFunctionsHere",
    OnComplete = "CanHaveJsFunctionsHere",
    UpdateTargetId = "transactions-results"
}))
{
    //whatever properties you want to post must be part of the model as that is what will be sent back.
}

<div id="transactions-results">
    @Html.Partial("NewsFeedPartial")
</div>
```